# Services 3.x json cache for anonymous user

Tags: 7, caching, services

Does the services module always invoke php to return data in json format? Is there anyway to cache the json output to be served for anonymous users (i.e. retrieve json data without invoking php)? First request will hit php and all subsequent hits should hit the cache.

My endpoint looks like this `api/anon` and it does not have any session authentication.

My request looks like this `http://localhost/api/anon/node/[nid]`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even in my experience, the boost module doesn't seem to cache responses from the Services module end points the last time I tried. But here's a discussion on this topic in the module's issue tracker. There's a patch for this requirement http://drupal.org/node/1219484

Answer (score 1):

I feel like something such as [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) would be more suited to this than trying to do it all in Drupal. The stock varnish configuration does a pretty good job at caching content that the backend says is safe to cache.

Answer (score 0):

For json response use rest server.

For static cache use boost module, for caching responses as static pages.

Comment: Unfortunately boost doesn't recognize the json path that comes from services. I want to know a smart to tell services to cache json output if "session authentication" in unchecked.

Comment: Yes it does, please check your boost settings including htaccess update. On boost settings you have to enable json extension.

Comment: Yes I have already done stuff you mentioned. But I always get the headers as "X-Drupal-Cache : Miss". Not sure if this is a bug from services module.